# Datepicker not binding formatted value

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

This is probably an easy question, but I'm having a problem with [this datepicker](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker). The problem is I set the format to `dd/mm/yyyy` with `data-date-format` attribute. However, when checking my `ng-model` the value is the following: `Wed Jul 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Standard Time)`

What I want is it to bind to `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

How can I fix this?

**Here is my code:**

```
<label for="inputDateFrom">Frá</label>
<div class="control-group input-append">
    <input type="text" ng-model="booking.Booking.DateFrom" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" bs-datepicker>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
</div>
```

**Update 18.07.13:**

According to rGil's answer I tried to use $scope.$watch. It works fine but first it gets the CORRECT date (from getBooking() service function), then it changes to the CURRENT date - which is not the date.

**JavaScript code is following:**

```
$scope.$watch('booking.Booking.DateFrom', function(v){ // using the example model from the datepicker docs
    $scope.booking.Booking.DateFrom = moment(v).format();
    alert(moment(v).format());
});

$scope.$watch('booking.Booking.DateTo', function(v){ // using the example model from the datepicker docs
    $scope.booking.Booking.DateTo = moment(v).format();
    alert(moment(v).format());
});

// Sækjum staka bókun
if(bookingID != null) {
    BookingService.getBooking(bookingID).then(function(data) {
        $scope.booking = data.data;
        $scope.booking.Booking.DateFrom = moment($scope.booking.Booking.DateFrom);
        $scope.booking.Booking.DateTo = moment($scope.booking.Booking.DateTo);
    });
}
```

**Then my HTML is the following:**

```
<label for="inputDateFrom">Frá</label>
<div class="control-group input-append">
        <input type="text" ng-model="booking.Booking.DateFrom" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" bs-datepicker>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
</div>

<label for="inputDateTo">Til</label>
<div class="control-group input-append">
        <input type="text" ng-model="booking.Booking.DateTo" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" bs-datepicker>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can easily be done without a plugin. Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/2013981) you can create a $scope variable with the correct formatting.

Example:

```
$scope.$watch('datepicker.date', function(v){ // using the example model from the datepicker docs
    var d = new Date(v);
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    $scope.modDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
    console.log($scope.modDate)
})
```

[FORKED DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/aUvyvOmZRYOCI0yHXiRV?p=preview) - open console

Comment: Maybe you can help me further with this example you provided for me. The first alert I get is the correct one (from getBooking() service), then the second one is the CURRENT date.

I updated my post. Please help me.

Answer (score 10):

Looking over the AngularStrap source code, I found that if you set the (seemingly undocumented) attribute `date-type` to any value outside of "Date" (for example: `String`) this prevents `bs-datpicker` from returning the selected date as a date object and  solves the issue. So in this case it would be:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="booking.Booking.DateFrom" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" date-type="string" bs-datepicker>
```

Tested on AngularStrap `v0.7.4` and `v0.7.5`

Comment: The solution for me was to just use the `date-type="string"`.  If I included the `date-format` the date was not correct.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to do it in a more elegant way, with AngularJS. Just use the date filter Angular. Like this:

```
$filter('date')(date, "yy/MM/yyyy", date.getTimezoneOffset())
```

$filter('date') gets the angularjs filter that take in args, the date, the template and the timezone, and returns a well formatted string.

```
08/03/2016
```